# How to add production mode to sailsjs app when started using PM2

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

To start sailsjs in production mode you append `--prod`.

Run:
`node app.js --prod`

I'm using PM2 and a simple json file for settings, which contains name of process and scriptname, to kick off the node process.

How would I pass the production argument using PM2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [**PM2 JSON app declaration**](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#json-app-declaration). E.g. (not tested)

```
[{
  "name"      : "Sails",
  "script"    : "./app.js",
  "args"      : "['--prod']"
}]
```

Comment: Typical.. Already tested this earlier, got a weird error, thought that the args wasn't properly passed, so I removed it. Looks like that wasn't the problem at all. Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

first delete:
`pm2 delete app`

again:

`pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this:

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official document](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment) you can do it like this:

```
pm2 start app.js -x --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

For pm2 if you have created **ecosystem.config.js** which you should create in the first process according to this  [official document](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/). By default it will consider development mode and if you want to change then first delete the previous instance with following command.

```
pm2 delete <ID|APP_NAME|SCRIPT|ALL|JSON>
```

Then you start the instance with following command.

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

And to check the process tail the logs of pm2 with following command.

```
pm2 logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration file for PM2 and I have running multiple service under PM2 as one of them below, `apps.json`

```html
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name"       : "TEST_APP",
      "script"     : "./app.js",
      "cwd"        : "/Users/username/app",
      "merge_logs" : true,
      "out_file"   : "logs/pm2-out.log",
      "error_file" : "logs/pm2-err.log",
      "instances"  : 3,
      "exec_mode"  : "cluster",
      "env"        : {
                        "NODE_ENV": "dev",
                        "PORT": "9999"
                     }, 
      "env_production": {
                        "NODE_ENV": "production",
                        "PORT": 9998
                     }  
    }
  ]
}
```

Then simply run the following command to run your service,

```
$ pm2 start apps.json --env production
```

You can include other parameters as mentioned in the [PM2 docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js  -- --prod

2.

> NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js --name "myapp" -i max -- --prod