# sails js set environment production

Tags: node.js, deployment, sails.js

i try to  set node_env= production on my server 
it doesn't work 
when i try to run

```
sails lift --prod
```

i have an error

```
    Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

and sails run on port 1337 
i set port forwarding using this command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

now i have sails app run on port 80 
but still  sails env development 
i need ti change env to manage my assets
my production.js file :-

```
  appUrl:'http://myserver.me/'

   models: {
    connection: 'someMysqlServer'
   },
   port: 80,
```

when i use

```
sails.config.appUrl
```

output :- http://localhost:1337  returned from development.js not production.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find solution as mentioned here : [How to add production mode to sailsjs app when started using PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055633/how-to-add-production-mode-to-sailsjs-app-when-started-using-pm2)

```
pm2 start app.js -x --prod
```