# Connecting app to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, devops

I'm pretty new to DevOps and I'm trying to set up my Node.js app on a AWS server instance. Steps I've taken:

1. Set up Elastic IP
2. Launched EC2 instance with Ubuntu server
3. Connected IP to instance
4. Allowed incoming connections on port 3000
5. SSH'd into the server with a .pem file

Now I'm at the point where I need to get my files uploaded to the server. I've used FileZilla (and like it) in the past to upload files but the initial part was already set up. When I set up the site on FileZilla there is no `/var/www` folder on the remote site.

[image]

[image]

Don't know how to connect these dots.

Also not sure what I need to run once I successfully upload the files. I imagine `npm install` when I'm ssh'd into the server? Most of the tutorials out there only go through the basic instance setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have `/var/www`. Also, it's better that you use a version control and a remote repository like Github and then SSH to your EC2 and then clone your repository there.

Then `cd` into your repo and run `npm install` and then start your app.

And check.

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect to the EC2 instance then clone your code in there. It not mandatory to be in `/var/www/html` but, it's best practice to keep it there. Once you clone `npm install` into your project home directory so all the required packages get installed. Then for running your node application in production you have to run it on service as pm2, supervisor, forever, passenger, etc. You can use any of these services and configured appropriately to run your application on desired port. As with pm2, you can follow this guide, [install pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) Then you can run with the following command w.r.t. your environment, like I want to run my application on port 5555 for production

```
$ PORT=5555 pm2 start app.js --name API --env production -f
```

Check the status using `pm2 list` Now, your application is running on http://server-ip:5555/ But, you won't be typing port number every-time. So, you need to configure the web server in front of your application like apache or nginx which will forward all request to your application running port. You could find the best guide to their home page. Then your application is available at http://server-ip/ You can follow this [for single configuration of multiple node apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178165/4671027)

Hope this helps.